# read half of a text file in R

Tags: r

If I have a text file like this:

```
# This is a text file
# Here is info about the data that
# will be of an undetermined
# length

# Data set 1
1,61
2,79
3,65
4,10
5,82

# Data set 2
1,61
2,75
3,27
4,27
5,94
```

How can I tell R to read in `Data set 1` but not `Data set 2`? The length of each data set is variable and updated dynamically. `Data set 2` will always start after a comment char as above though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that file is saved as `"70626963.txt"`, then there are two methods:

```r
txt <- readLines("~/StackOverflow/9454855/70626963.txt")
read.csv(text = txt[nzchar(txt) & cumsum(!nzchar(txt)) == 1], skip = 1, header = FALSE)
#   V1 V2
# 1  1 61
# 2  2 79
# 3  3 65
# 4  4 10
# 5  5 82
```

and

```r
read.csv(pipe("sed -ne '/Data set 1/,/Data set 2/{/Data set/d;p}' 70626963.txt"), header = FALSE)
#   V1 V2
# 1  1 61
# 2  2 79
# 3  3 65
# 4  4 10
# 5  5 82
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I can make that work for my application. It is a PITA that the data are archived like this.